# Sets well ordered under different operations Proving

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, well-orders

$(a)\quad R^+ \cup \{0\}, <$

$(b)\quad [0,1], >$

$(c)\quad \text{The set of integers divisible by 5}, <$

$(d)\quad \{\{0,1,...,n\}|n ∈ N\},⊆$

I believe that:

> (a) Is not well-ordered because of the fact that rational numbers would be in a continuous flow and would be infinitely smaller.
>
> (b) Is not well-ordered, because (0,1) as a subset would break the ability of it.
>
> (c) Is not well-ordered, because the set of integers could go to negative infinity, making the set not have a value that can satisfy the less than requirement.
>
> (d) Is well ordered, as 0 is the smallest element of subsets in the set of {0,1,...,n}

Are my beliefs correct on these scenarios, and how would I go about trying to actually prove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, they're correct. For (a)-(c) you've essentially already proved them **through contradiction**. Try to write them out in more detail.

Here's a sketch of (a): Take the rationals in $(0,1)$. If it had a minimum $q$, then take the midpoint of $0$ and $q$, contradiction.